# Get String Value from NSDictionary

Tags: cocoa, nsstring, nsdictionary

I have the following code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *jsonObj = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];
NSString *test = [[[jsonObj objectForKey:@"questions"] valueForKey:@"owner"] valueForKey:key];
```

but what I get back is:

```
 (
1a19f089a2bc4ee42bff1c102c6e89b8
)
```

The actual value is fine, but I get those parenthesis, which show up in my string.  How can I get rid of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`-stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-CJBJFBGC) with e.g. an [inverted](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000157-invertedSet) [alphanumeric character set](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000157-CJBDAFFF) should work fine here:

```
cleanStr = [str stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
            [[NSCharacterSet alphaNumericCharacterSet] invertedSet]];
```

But actually that sounds like either the provider of the JSON or the parser should be fixed.

Comment: thanks.  I found the bug though.  It turns out my NSString should be an NSArray and I what I had to get was objAtIndex:0.  I'll accept your answer anyway because I need this code later on in my app